# Newbie question re opening and reading a csv file in python

Tags: python, csv

Older, retired programmer trying to learn python and having a problem that's very basic but I can't figure it out.  I have the following code which I copied from a tutorial, and I created a path to the data I want to play with. Code as follows:

```
import csv
file = open('C:\Users\me\Documents\projects\cointest\edata.csv','r') as csv_file
csvreader = csv.reader(file)
header = next(csvreader)
print(header)
rows = []
for row in csvreader:
    rows.append(row)
print(rows)
file.close()
```

I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'csvreader' is not defined
>>> print(header)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'header' is not defined
>>> rows = []
>>> for row in csvreader:
...     rows.append(row)
...     print(rows)
... file.close()
  File "<stdin>", line 4
    file.close()
^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: If you're executing the code in the REPL, you need a blank line after the indented block.

Comment: Don't copy and paste the entire thing into an interactive console. Write it in a .py file, execute it with `python myfile.py`…

Comment: Also, delete the `as csv_file` part at the end of line 2. It's not needed. And finally, your file path should be a raw string literal - `r'C:\Users\me\Documents\projects\cointest\edata.csv'`.

Comment: *as* is used with *with* (Work Manager) Take @MattDMo's advice